# JavaFx Android Application would not display correctly

Tags: javafxports

My Javafx app does not display anything, it displays a blank screen on the android device. What can i do? Thank you I have created the android apk, and also Installed it on an android device, but it still does not display anything. What have i not done?

Comment: With your device plugged, open a terminal, navigate to <your Android SDK folder>/platform-tools`,  then run `adb logcat` to find a possible exception. Then try to fix the exception or post it here if you can't.

Comment: Thank you i would try doing that